# NET_RENDER keep getting RuntimeError: Error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Tags: python, rendering, network

I'm trying to make a net_render render farm on a cloud platform and I keep getting "RuntimeError: Error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe". code dump:

```
Fra:45 Mem:16.44M (0.00M, Peak 16.86M) | Time:00:19.98 | Mem:0.30M, Peak:0.58M | Scene, RenderLayer | Finished
Fra:45 Mem:16.11M (0.00M, Peak 16.86M) | Time:00:19.98 | Sce: Scene Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Saved: '/tmp/slave_9f3670cf93a444bc5a9c67184c0e2e97/job_1/000045.exr'
 Time: 00:20.15 (Saving: 00:00.17)


Blender quit
status 0
Error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/client.py", line 367, in render
    raise e
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/client.py", line 360, in render
    self.render_slave(scene)
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/client.py", line 387, in render_slave
    slave.render_slave(self, scene.network_render, scene.render.threads)
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/slave.py", line 390, in render_slave
    conn.request("PUT", "/render", f, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

location: /usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:187

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/client.py", line 367, in render
    raise e
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/client.py", line 360, in render
    self.render_slave(scene)
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/client.py", line 387, in render_slave
    slave.render_slave(self, scene.network_render, scene.render.threads)
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/slave.py", line 390, in render_slave
    conn.request("PUT", "/render", f, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1065, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 986, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

location: /usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:187

location: /usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:187
Fra:1 Mem:15.78M (0.00M, Peak 15.80M) | Time:15:34.19 | Sce: Scene Ve:0 Fa:0 La:0
Error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/operators.py", line 97, in execute
    bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_AREA', animation=True)
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 187, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
RuntimeError: Error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe


location: /usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:189

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/operators.py", line 97, in execute
    bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_AREA', animation=True)
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 187, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
RuntimeError: Error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe


location: /usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:189

location: /usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:189
Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/operators.py", line 97, in execute
    bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_AREA', animation=True)
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 187, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
RuntimeError: Error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe


location: /usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:189

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/blender/netrender/slave.py", line 8, in <module>
    bpy.ops.render.netclientstart()
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 189, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/operators.py", line 97, in execute
    bpy.ops.render.render('INVOKE_AREA', animation=True)
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 187, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), C_dict, kw, C_exec, C_undo)
RuntimeError: Error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe


location: /usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py:189



Blender quit
```

I get this output from the slave computer ^

I also get a smaller output on the master computer:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('10.0.0.5', 60156)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 418, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 406, in handle_one_request
    method()
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/master.py", line 843, in do_PUT
    self.write_file(job.getResultPath(frame.getRenderFilename()))
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/netrender/master.py", line 236, in write_file
    length = int(self.headers['content-length'])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
----------------------------------------
```

in terms of the topology of the network, three machines are on a virtual network. there's a client (my laptop, Windows 10) a master (a VM, Ubuntu) and a slave (another VM, Ubuntu).

any ideas whats going on?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.blender.org/rBAf975292b1ec103826fe244dfdb851fed0428b624 solves everything :)

this is just a commit made by a user, I just downloaded and replaced all the required files.